# Data Tables Sort Not Working Correctly for "bServerSide": true,

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I am using latest version of datatable (1.10). If i use  "bServerSide": true Default sorting is not working 
if i comment "bServerSide": true, then top filter is not working

```
var oTable = $('#list_order').dataTable( {
             'destroy': true,
              'bAutoWidth': false ,                                     
               "bProcessing": true,
              "bServerSide": true,
                "bFilter": false,
               "bRetrieve": true,
            "bSort": true,
            "aaSorting": [[1, 'desc']],
             'aoColumnDefs': [
                    { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [3,4,5] },
                    { "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false,"aTargets": [0] }
                            ]  ,    
                                "sAjaxSource":"orders/server_list_orders",

                              "iDisplayStart ":20,
                               "iDisplayLength": 25,

                               "fnInitComplete": function() {

                                     },
                                            'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
                                        {

                                          var formData_topSearch = $("#list_orders").serializeArray();   
                                              aoData = $.merge(aoData, formData_topSearch);


                                          $.ajax
                                          ({
                                            'dataType': 'json',
                                            'type'    : 'POST',
                                            'url'     : sSource,
                                            'data'    : aoData,
                                            'success' : fnCallback
                                          });
                                        }
                                });

                                $('#list_orders').change(function(){
    $('#list_order').dataTable().fnSortNeutral();
});
```

Please help me to find a solution